# Parse JSON with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am currently developing an application for managing appointments on iOS, I am a beginner and I confess that I have a little trouble parsing my JSON, I come to you to ask for a little help :)

Here is a little piece of my appointments JSON:

```
data{
         "Sunday, August 10, 2014" = {
            timeslots = (
                            {
                    id = 1013;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 5:15 p.m.;
                    timestart = 5:00 p.m;
                }
                            {
                    id = 1045;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 5:30 p.m.;
                    timestart = 5:15 p.m.;
                }
            );
        };
        "Sunday, July 13, 2014" = {
            timeslots = (
                            {
                    id = 705;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 4:00 P.m;
                    timestart = 3:45 p.m.;
                }
                            {
                    id = 725;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 4:15 p.m.;
                    timestart = 4:00 p.m;
                }
                            {
                    id = 745;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 4:30 p.m
                    timestart = 4:15 p.m.;
                }
                            {
                    id = 1009;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 5:15 p.m.;
                    timestart = 5:00 p.m;
                }
                            {
                    id = 1041;
                    idPatient = "<null>"
                    status = 0;
                    timeEnd = 5:30 p.m.;
                    timestart = 5:15 p.m.;
                }
            );
        }
};
```

I synthesize the code a bit for something more readable

```
- (void)retrieveData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData *allData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    NSDictionary *data = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"];

    for (NSDictionary *oneDay in data)
    {
        NSArray *keys = [oneDay allKeys];
    }
}
```

And the error message :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e68010'
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: @vikingosegundo - At first glance it appears to be an NSLog dump of valid parsed JSON.  (Other than the initial "data", that is -- it's not clear whether that's a key with a missing `=` or simply a literal value in the NSLog statement.)

Comment: What exactly does this dump: `NSLog(@"%@", data);`?  Give us the first 30 characters or so.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you get from `[oneDay objectForKey:@"timeslots"]`??

Comment: The exact error is : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x9e31f80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key timeslots.' Thanks a lot !

Comment: So you are attempting to use the objectForKey on an NSString. This is because iterating on an NSDictionary give you the key, not the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its because timeslots is under "Sunday, August 10, 2014" this dictionary. Its second layer. First retrieve "Sunday, August 10, 2014" dictionary then you will be able to access timeslot array.

Modify your for loop like below

```
for (NSDictionary *oneDay in data)
    {
        NSDictionary *dData = [oneDay objectForKey:@"Sunday, August 10, 2014"];
        NSDictionary *tslots = [dData objectForKey:@"timeslots"];
        NSLog(@"%@", tslots); // unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b63860

        NSArray *keys = [tslots allKeys];
        for (NSString *key in keys)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key, [oneDay objectForKey:key]);
        }

        [days addObject:oneDay];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response !I have considered your proposal, one little thing, "Sunday, August 10, 2014" is variable, so I can not put [oneday objectForKey: @ "Sunday, August 10, 2014" ]; like this, an idea to make the whole dynamic? (sorry for my english ^^ google translate :p)

Comment: The for loop should be indexing through `data`, accessing each dictionary element already.  The one thing I can never remember is whether it fetches each value or rather each key.  I'm thinking key, so one would need to do `[data objectForKey:oneDayKey]` or some such.

Comment: Do [oneDay allKeys] it will return you keys array. Now you can retrieve data [oneDay objectForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
It will be dynamic.

Comment: id response = [oneDay objectForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:i]];
Further you can check type of returning value by if([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) then parse accordingly.

Comment: When i try : [oneDay allKeys], it return : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cd7400'. I don't know why :|

Comment: Ok it works. I replaced for(NSDictionary *oneDay in data) by for(int i = 0; i < data.count; i++), and I followed your instructions. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

your json response is wrong. Please check with this link http://json.parser.online.fr/ and once you get the proper response try to parse it. will work easily.

Comment: It's the result of an NSLog statement. Most people here are used to that. Should be obvious that since JSONObjectWithData: parsed _something_, there must be valid JSON somewhere.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes you are right its NSLog statement but it has some problem inside that's way its not showing error free in online json parser. get the complete response first then you can say surely.

Comment: I just copy / paste my full json on the site you given me and I have no error messages .. :O

Comment: @user3771020 can u post the complete json response with no error??

Comment: Yes I can, hmm, I just want to clarify that the application returns me well my JSON when I do a NSLog (@ "% @", data) :D So i think my JSON is good no ?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...

```
for (NSString *oneDayKey in data)
{
    NSDictionary *oneDay = [data objectForKey:oneDayKey];
    NSArray *keys = [oneDay allKeys];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If enumeration a dictionary you can get the key and the object at once.

```
[data enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id dayKey, id dayDict, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dayDict);
}];
```